# Best way to manage a list of classes that needs to be accessible throughout in a UWP project

Tags: c#, list, uwp

I currently have a list of class objects that is a global variable in my UWP project so that it can be accessed from all pages.

I want populate this list from a file when I run the program.

The function for reading from a file is an async function and I am not sure which part of the code is best to populate the list.

I have tried this in App.xaml.cs:

```
public static List<Class> classList = new List<Class>();   

public App()
        {
            classList = await Files.ReadFromFileAsync<List<Class>>(filePath);

            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }
```

However this doesn't work as the App() method is and cannot be async, I assume that this is completely the wrong way to go about doing this.

**Have three main questions:**

1. Is there a way to make this work?
2. Is there a better way to do this with a global list?
3. Is there a way of passing lists between pages that doesn't require local variables that is even better than that?

Comment: It would be great if you could show us some code to serve as context.

Comment: I have updated the question to have more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Is there a way to make this work?

You can create an asynchronous method, put async function in it and then call this method in App constructor. Note that if the async function takes a long time, when the page has beed loaded, the list may not be populated yet.

```
public App()
{
    getLists();
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
}

public async void getLists() 
{
    classList = await Files.ReadFromFileAsync<List<Class>>(filePath);
}
```

> > Is there a better way to do this with a global list?

You can also put the async funtion in the OnLaunched method in App.xaml.cs, before your page is loaded, the list has been populated, but it will prolong the splash screen.

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    classList = await Files.ReadFromFileAsync<List<Class>>(filePath);
    ......
}
```

> > Is there a way of passing lists between pages

When you navigate from one page to another, you can pass the list to the navigate method, like:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), new List<string>());
```

And you can receive the list from the OnNavigatedTo method in Page1.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    List<string> lists = e.Parameter as List<string>;
}
```